# MIB monitoring for HP Servers

Tags: snmp, oid

We have a bunch of Dell servers being monitored (particulary the RAID) using SNMP. To monitor the RAID array we use this OIDs:

Virtual Disk State : 1.3.6.1.4.1.674.10893.1.20.140.1.1.4

Array Disk State : 1.3.6.1.4.1.674.10893.1.20.130.4.1.4

With those 2 OID we can get an alarm that tell us if the virtual disk is having issues or the physical disks.

This OIDs works for all Dell Servers.

Now we've got a Proliant DL380 G7 and we need to do the same monitoring for this device.

I've found online the MIBs that apparently works (https://h20566.www2.hpe.com/hpsc/swd/public/detail?swItemId=MTX_ad470f02a64f416eb686f2525e) but there are too many OIDs.

Do you guys know if the RAID array can be monitored using SNMP on this Proliant?.

Thanks so much.

Regards.
Francisco.